# jQuery: Selecting a option value and make the checkbox name follow

Tags: jquery

This is my goal, this is only static though:

http://jsfiddle.net/ySu7q/

I wish to make this dynamic, so the related checkbox below follow what value you have chosen in the select box.

I would like to do when you select in the current '18:00' select box, and change it to another e.g 19:00 - then the checkbox below should follow and change to 1900 both the display text and the name should be changed from `copyTime[1][1800]` to `copyTime[1][1900]`

How can I do this? I have no clue where to start, maybe the structure of the current code should be rewritten to make it possible?

Thanks alot

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Using Safari nothing happens.

Comment: He wrote it's static. He described the desired behaviour in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a possible solution:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        time = $this.val(),
        $checkbox = $('#'+$this.attr('data-checkbox')),
        $checkbox_label = $('label[for="'+$this.attr('data-checkbox')+'"]');

    $checkbox.attr('name', 'copyTime[1]['+time+']');
    $checkbox_label.text(time);
});​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ySu7q/1/

Definitely not perfect but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".select").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":first-child"))
        $(".label:first-child").html($(this).val());
    else if($(this).is(":last-child"))
        $(".label:last-child").html($(this)val());
    else
        $(".label").eq(1).html($(this).val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

http://jsfiddle.net/ySu7q/2/

It's what you want ?

Comment: This is changing the value and not the name :-)

Answer (score 0):

So:

use this way to checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="copyTime[1][1800]" value="1" CHECKED> <span>1800</span>
```

This is the JS:

```
$('select').on('change', function(){

    var ind = $(this).index();
    var newVal = $(this).val().replace(':', '');
    //alert($("input:checkbox").eq(ind).attr('name'));
    $("input:checkbox").eq(ind).attr('name', 'copyTime[1]['+newVal+']');
    $("input:checkbox").eq(ind).next('span').html(newVal);

});
```

This the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epCbv/)